# Printing using textPrinter in Ubuntu

Tags: java, printing, network-printers

I using [this library](http://www.java4less.com/textprinter/index.html) for printing, and I am using Ubuntu.

My code is the following:

```
FilePort port=new FilePort("\\\\printerIp:631\\printers\\Hewlett-Packard-HP-LaserJet-Professional-P1606dn");
TextPrinter printer=PrinterFactory.getPrinter("HP-PCL5");
```

However I am not able to print. When I use

`FilePort port=new FilePort("\home\hi.txt")`

the text is getting printed in `hi.txt` file.

I tried `\dev\lpr` but it is giving me error

```
com.java4less.textprinter.exceptions.CouldNotOpenPrinterException: /dev/lpr (Permission denied)
FilePort port=new FilePort("\dev\lpr");
```

Here is my full source code

```
try {

    FilePort port = new FilePort("\\\\10.9.42.136:631\\printers\\Hewlett-Packard-HP-LaserJet-Professional-P1606dn");
    // get printer supporting HP-PCL command set
    TextPrinter printer = PrinterFactory.getPrinter("HP-PCL5");

    // create printing job
    JobProperties job = printer.getDefaultJobProperties();
    job.landscape = true;
    printer.startJob(port, job);

    // print BOLD text
    TextProperties prop = printer.getDefaultTextProperties();
    prop.bold = true;
    printer.printString("This must be BOLD", prop);
    printer.newLine();
    printer.newLine();
    printer.printString("Hello world..", prop);
    // print line
    printer.printHorizontalLine(5,0,80);            // row 5, column 0 to 80

    printer.endJob();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit some permissions first, try this

edit the file in **/etc/cups/cupsd.conf**

search for **lpadmin** and change it to **lp**